# Powershell: Run GUI with other user

Tags: powershell

I'm going nuts...

Target: Server starts. Powershell is executed as Service and App runs.

When I log on as admnin, the program runs, but the GUI is hidden. i have to kill the processs and restart as logged on user.

is there a way to start an app and make it visible to all users that log on?

PS1: Start-Process -FilePath "C:..\xy.exe" -LoadUserProfile "Administrator"

-Credential $credential & -LoadUserProfile "Administrator" didn't work

Edit: It's a server with a software. No user issues.
The VPS can suddenly reboot or some issue else. Plan is to somehow automate the startup, that the SW runs on startup. But then it's not available when a user logs in. it runs hidden or whatever..

plan was a PS1 in a winTask at startup - but can be anything that works. Autologon is somehow a pretty security thing...

tried the idea with the shortcuts, although a start works then, the gui is not available at first.

Comment: How are you running it? Using Task Scheduler?

Comment: Task manager for users (not admin) only show processes started with system and the user who is logged in.  Not tasks started by other users.  So you would have to start as System.  Best way is to create a shortcut to app and then give permission of shortcut to run as System.  Any shortcuts you be placed in the All Users folder so everybody is using same shortcut.

Comment: @jdweng from a security perspective this is the worst advice you can give. To answer the question: you can't show a GUI app started as a different user using Powershell (not without going through a lot of hoops like registering a service OR by using impersonation). The easiest way to start a GUI app for your users is task scheduler

Comment: @bluuf : You have no idea what the app does to be able to say there is a security risk.  Scheduled tasks are run at specific times and this task may need to be run ASAP.

Comment: Running an application or script under the system account ALWAYS poses a security risk.